# How to allow only single UIViewController to rotate upside down with Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, autorotate

In my app all screens have portrait orientation. How to allow only single UIViewController be in two orientation mode: portrait and upside down? When user rotates an iPhone, the UIViewController should rotates too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, In your application all screens except one screen are in portrait orientation. So You cannot set orientation of your application as portrait. So Set Device Orientation as portrait and LandScape both.

Put following code on which screen you need landscape orientation in ViewDidLoad

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

and

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
return true
}
```

Put following code on all screens where you need only portrait orientation in viewDidLoad

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't neet landscape mode, only portrait and upside down in one UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you have any function that continuously called then you can check the device orientation inside this function as-

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown {
    // set your view constraints
}

if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait {
    // set your view constraints 
}
```

Otherwise you should create a monitoring function and check device orientation inside the function.

Comment: I need such logic: when user takes an iPhone in portrait orientation, UIViewController looks in portrait orientation, if user takes in upside down orientation, the same UIViewController looks in upside down orientation

Comment: Yes, I got it. When you get the upsideDown orientation you should change your view constraints. I mean new design for your view.

Comment: And at first, set your project device orientation only portrait. After this, your view will not change for landscape mode.